# Clang: How to pass multiple arguments to clang plugin

Tags: clang

Basically when I try to pass my_arg_1 to my clang plugin, it look like this:

`-Xclang -load -Xclang my-plugin-library -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang plugin_name -Xclang -plugin-arg-plugin_name -Xclang my_arg_1`

Now if I want to pass an extra arguments, what I do is:

`....... -Xclang my_arg_1 -Xclang my_arg_2`

But face an error:

```
error: error reading my_arg_2
```

Does anyone know the syntax of Clang to pass n extra arguments to clang plugin ?

Thankyou
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just repeat -Xclang -plugin-arg-plugin_name:

`clang ... -Xclang -plugin-arg-plugin_name -Xclang my_arg_1 -Xclang -plugin-arg-plugin_name -Xclang my_arg_2 ...`